# Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing

I just want to ask for help since I do not know if what this error caused my program not to run.

Before I went here to ask for help, I did a little testing and debbuging in order for me to locate if what was the root caused of the error when I try to run my program. see the code below

```
  public class AcademicPersonnelForm{

 public AcademicPersonnelForm(){
   create();
}

    public static void main(String [] args){


 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

new AcademicPersonnelForm();

    }   
 });


}//close main
```

below is my method called "create()" where I created my JFrame. inside this method i declare all the necesarry components I needed to be inserted in the Frame.(component included only where the error occured)

```
      public void create(){

      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
gbc.ipady = 20;
gbc.ipadx = 20;
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
gbc.gridheight = 1;

textEmpNo.addKeyListener(new MyRetrieve());

     textEmpNo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,5));

     textEmpNo.setDocument(new LengthRestrictedDocument(3));
     //add textEmpNo in the main panel              
     gbl.setConstraints(textEmpNo, gbc);
     mainPanel.add(textEmpNo);

            }
```

I found out that the error mentioned above occured in "textEmpNo.addKeyListener(new MyRetrieve());", because when I tried to put comment in this code the program works fine.

"new MyRetrieve()" is a subclass where I can generate and retrieve employee number. see code below.

```
      public class MyRetrieve implements KeyListener{

     search_employee_record_db serdb = new search_employee_record_db();
     generate_emp_num_db gendb = new generate_emp_num_db();


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){



    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){ 

    serdb.EMPNUM = textEmpNo.getText();


     //if(serdb.EmpNo.equals(textEmpNo.getText())){
    if(textEmpNo.getText().equals(serdb.EMPNUM)){


     serdb.retrieved();

    //textEmpNo.setText(serdb.EmpNo);

    textFName.setText(serdb.FName);
    textLName.setText(serdb.LName);
    comboGender.setSelectedItem(serdb.GENDER);
    textAddress.setText(serdb.address);

    comboDay.setSelectedItem(serdb.DAY);
         comboMonth.setSelectedItem(serdb.MONTH);
         comboYear.setSelectedItem(serdb.YEAR);

         textSSS.setText(serdb.sss);
         textReligion.setText(serdb.religion);
    textCitizenship.setText(serdb.citizenship);
         textTIN.setText(serdb.tin);
               textMobileNo.setText(serdb.mobileNumber);
    comboStatus.setSelectedItem(serdb.STATUS);
    comboDHDay.setSelectedItem(serdb.DH_DAY);
    comboDHMonth.setSelectedItem(serdb.DH_MONTH);
    comboDHYear.setSelectedItem(serdb.DH_YEAR);


    update.setEnabled(true);
    }//end of if

          if(serdb.EMPNUM.equalsIgnoreCase("")){


    gendb.generate();

          textEmpNo.setText(gendb.INC);

          comboGender.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboMonth.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDay.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboYear.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDHMonth.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDHDay.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDHYear.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboStatus.setSelectedIndex(0);
     textLName.setText("");
     textFName.setText("");
     textAddress.setText("");
     textSSS.setText("");
     textReligion.setText("");
     textTIN.setText("");
     textCitizenship.setText("");
     textMobileNo.setText("");


   }//end of if


  else if(!textEmpNo.getText().equals(serdb.EmpNo)){

     comboGender.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboMonth.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDay.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboYear.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDHMonth.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDHDay.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboDHYear.setSelectedIndex(0);
     comboStatus.setSelectedIndex(0);
     textLName.setText("");
     textFName.setText("");
     textAddress.setText("");
     textSSS.setText("");
     textReligion.setText("");
     textTIN.setText("");
     textCitizenship.setText("");
     textMobileNo.setText("");


  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"employee number does not exist");     


   textEmpNo.selectAll();   


    }//end of else if

    }//end of outer if   

     } //end method

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO: Do something for the keyTyped event
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO: Do something for the keyPressed event
        }


   }//close inner class
```

can someone explain to me why the mentioned above error occured. thanks

Comment: Select better class class names using Java naming convention. Class names being with capitals, using camel casing e.g. `search_employee_record_db` could be `SearchEmployeeRecordDB`

Comment: Lets start with, you should be using an `ActionListener` to monitor for "action" events, like [Enter].  `KeyListener` is a very poor choice for text components...

Comment: Seems problem in `search_employee_record_db` or `generate_emp_num_db` class.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not really familiar with all the Java naming convention, but i will follow if what you have told me. thanks btw.

Comment: Show us the stack trace that the exception prints. It will tell exactly where to look for the error.

Comment: I Found the error! It seemed to have a recurrion in search_employee_record_db  generate_emp_num_db. which caused the error mentioned above. @alex2410. thanks for the info. =)

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188) or delete the question itself.